# How to crack encrypted Android SQLite DB?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, android, databases, decryption

I am testing an android app which has DB encrypted (AES-256), I extracted it from system files /data/data//databases, I have following doubts,

1. How do we ensure that DB is encrypted properly and it is not crackable.
2. What tools can we use to test it?
3. What are the different scenarios to test it?

Thanks in advance.

Also I have the key which is encrypted key.

Comment: @kelalaka, sorry i am new to security, can you please elaborate, which method are you talking about?

Comment: Well, assuming that the app encrypted the database. So the question is how? AES with 128,192,256 bit keys? or Chacha20 or, AES-GCM, or AES-SIV, or... without knowing this good luck. And even you know the methods without the keys again good luck. The besy way is understanding the app and trying to access the encryption key. Probably the key is generated from a password from a password based Key Derivation function. Therefore, don't expect to find the key.

Comment: If you are the tester (not a breaker) then test that given all information but the key. That is more realistic approach.

Comment: very nicely explained and thanks for your time kelalaka. So the method used is AES 256 and I got the key also. Please share your thought on decryption. thanks

Comment: You have the key! but in your question, it is not mentioned. Go on into the app and look at the implementation...